# Cleverref does not use default language after \foreignlanguage

Tags: errors, languages, cleveref

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% PACKAGES
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}\label{test}

\foreignlanguage{english}{here some english text..}
%\selectlanguage{ngerman}

german text.. \cref{test}.

\end{document}
```

The reference should be in german, because the default language is set to german. But cleverref always prints references in english language after `\foreignlanguage{english}{some english text..}`. I can avoid this strange behaviour by appending `\selectlanguage{ngerman}` but this look more like a hack instead of a real solution.

Does anyone have a solution for that (or do I misunderstand the concept of `\foreignlanguage`)?

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  Are your packages up to date?

Comment: The MWE works fine for me, too. (`cleveref.sty` 2013/12/28 v0.19)